# Как сюда приделать перегрузку ввода вывода?

Tags: c++

```cpp
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Student {
  public:
    string name;
  int classs;
  int pol;

  friend void getStudent(const Student & student);
};

void getStudent(const Student & student) {

  if (student.classs == 6 && student.pol == 1) {
    cout << "Учеников 6 класса:" << endl;
    cout << student.name << endl;
  } else
    return;
}

int main() {

  int x;
  cout << "Введите количество учеников" << endl;
  cin >> x;

  Student mass[x];
  for (int j = 0; j < x; ++j) {
    cout << "Введите фамилию ученика " << endl;
    cin >> mass[j].name;
    cout << "Введите номер класса ученика " << endl;
    cin >> mass[j].classs;
    cout << "Введите пол ученка ((м=1) / (ж=0)) " << endl;
    cin >> mass[j].pol;
  }

  for (int i = 0; i < x; ++i) {
    getStudent(mass[i]);
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: учитывая, что у Вас функция getStudent печатает имя студента по условию, хотел бы спросить, а что имется ввиду под перегрузкой ввода-вывода?

Comment: Описать дружественную функцию для вывода учеников 6 класса
мужского пола. В программе перегрузить операторы ввода и
вывода. Оригинал задачи.

Answer (score 0):

Перегрузка оператора вывода будет такая

```
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Student& st)
{
  os << st.name << " " << st.class << (st.pol == 1?'м':'ж');
  return os;
}
```

и теперь вместо странной функции getStudent, лучше написать

```
showSixGradeMaleStudent(const Student & student) {
  if (student.classs == 6 && student.pol == 1) {
    std::cout << student << '\n';
  }
}
```

а вот как оператор ввода для Вашей задачи перегрузить.... Возможно так, но я не уверен

```
std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& is, Student& s) {
  cout << "Введите фамилию ученика " << endl;
  is >> mass[j].name;
  cout << "Введите номер класса ученика " << endl;
  is >> mass[j].classs;
  cout << "Введите пол ученка ((м=1) / (ж=0)) " << endl;
  is >> mass[j].pol;
  return is;
}
```

вот только использование std::cout  в ней меня очень сильно-сильно напрягает.